# Condition to check recipients and forwarding message

Tags: vba, outlook

Im trying to write condition and depending on which recipient has an email forward it to another email. After searching in web I found following but its not work for me:

```
Public Sub ConvertMeetingToEmail(ActiveFolder, Inbox As String)

    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim Subfolder As Outlook.Folder

    Dim Item As Object
    Dim myMtg As Outlook.MeetingItem

    Dim objMsg As MailItem
    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = myNamespace.Folders(ActiveFolder)
    Set Folders = myFolder.Folders
    Set Subfolder = Folders.Item(Inbox)

    For Each Item In Subfolder.Items

        If Item.MessageClass = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request" Then
            Set Msg = Item
            Set recips = Msg.Recipients
            For Each recip In recips
                If (recip = "example@mail.domail" _
                    Or recip = "example1@mail.domail" _
                    Or recip = "example2@mail.domail" _
                    Or recip = "example3@mail.domail" _
                    Or recip = "example4@mail.domail") Then

                        objMsg.To = "example6@mail.domail"
                        objMsg.CC = recip
                        objMsg.Subject = Msg.Subject
                        objMsg.Body = Msg.Body
                        objMsg.Send
                Endif
            Next
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recipients collection returns Recipient objects, not strings, so your code should be checking the `recip.Address` property. It is also a good idea to use case insensitive string comparison:

```
 If ((StrComp(recip.Address, "example@mail.domail", 1) = 0) _
...
```

Comment: thanks, I did something different but your answer helped me come to this decision